# Land Administration Domain Model example implementations

Tags: modelling, land-survey

Does anybody know of a sample implementation? I am currently trying to adapt it to my country but the LADM is rather abstract. Anybody have any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to visit the LADM Wiki:

http://wiki.tudelft.nl/bin/view/Research/ISO19152/WebHome

Here you will find the complete LADM documentation, and the UML model.

Another suggestion is to go to:

http://flossola.org/

Here you will find open source software and a lot of documentation (data dictionnary included).

Further developments can be followed at www.fig.net and www.gltn.net

Christiaan Lemmen

Comment: I actually found the latest FDIS at http://www.wiki.tudelft.nl/pub/Research/ISO19152/IsoDocuments/ISO_FDIS_19152_11_May_2012.pdf. Though I think that was the private facing part of the wiki. I never did find the public facing side. Thanks a lot and congratulations on getting your PhD :)

Answer (score 3):

try to download document for LADM as pdf. you will get different country profiles from LADM. try to fit your requirements which ever suits you most.